# How to draw a stacked dotplot in R?

Tags: r, graphics, plot

Here is a plot ,how can i draw it in R?

[image]

Comment: What does your data look like? Edit the results of `head(your_data)` into your post.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The base R function is `stripchart`. <s>A minimal example</s> A worked out example:

```
set.seed(1); A <- sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE)
stripchart(A, method = "stack", offset = .5, at = .15, pch = 19, 
           main = "Dotplot of Random Values", xlab = "Random Values")
```

[image]

You can also play with `offset` to increasing the gap between the stacked points, and `pch` to change the point type.

Comment: how to make the  x-coordinate  into  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9  ;not 0,2,4,6,8?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: to change the x-axis tick marks, you can add `axes = FALSE` to your `stripchart` call and then run `axis(1, 1:10)`.

Answer (score 7):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) + geom_dotplot()
```

Comment: Please add the result of your code to improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: is this a down vote for not adding a picture? `mtcars` is a built in data set, so anyone can run this code. feel free to edit and add the figure if you'd like.

Answer (score -1):

FYI here is an example of the y-axis dot-plot:

```
downv<- data.frame(
y<- c(rep(3,14),6,6,9,9,9,9,9.5,9.5,10.5,10.5,10.5,10.5,rep(11,8)),
l2<- c(rep(8,4),rep(6,6),4,4,8,8,8,4,rep(6,6),8,8,4,4,rep(6,8)),
l<- c(rep(0,7,),rep(1,7),0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,rep(0,4),rep(1,4))
)

ggplot(downv, aes(x = factor(l), y = y, fill = factor(l2))) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", position = "dodge", dotsize=3,  stackratio = .7) + 
scale_fill_manual(values=c("black", "black", "black"))


#need square aspect ratio
```